# How to add event with Javascript to an html tag

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, dom-events

I've a landingpage with dynamic html tags.
The Problem is, that i can't select directly the tag. Its a link.
the following code is the construct:

```
<div id="testid"><div><div><a href="#">Button 1</a><div><div><div>
```

Every time someone clicks on the link (a-tag) I want to fire an event like the following code:

```
<a href="#" name="button1" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});">Button 1</a>
```

the question: what is the Javascript code to add the `onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'})` attribute to the a tag.

I tried the following code:

```
var d = document.getElementById("testid").firstchild;
d.setAttribute("onclick", "dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'})");
```

but it seems to the code is incorrect. The `a` tag is also not the first child; there are 2 divs between :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: you are missing quotes around id="testid"

Comment: Use `document.querySeletor('#test a')`

Comment: well; i correct it. But the Quotes aren't the problem

Comment: In that HTML, the `<a>` isn't a direct child of `#testid`. Can you post the HTML you actually have, with proper indentations?

Comment: i tried following
var d = document.querySeletor('#testid a')
d.setAttribute("onclick", "dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'})");

but i get this answer
VM4855:2 Uncaught TypeError: document.querySeletor is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:18

Comment: try `.querySelector`, with a `c`

Comment: `code`
<div id="testid">
<div>
<div>
 <a href="#">Linkname</a>
</div></div></div>
`code`

Comment: really reall thk you; i forgot the *c* :) thx for code below thank you guys. i'm little bit tired and dont see the *C* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var dataLayer = [];
    var d = document.querySelector("#testid a[name=button1]");
    d.addEventListener("click", function () {
        dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'button1-click' });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>repl.it</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="testid">
  <div>
   <div>
    <a href="#" name="button1">Button 1</a>
    <div>
     <div>
      <div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js">

 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There's a few things you were missing from your JS.

1. Using a more specific selector (`#testid a[name=button1]` vs. the `firstchild` of `#testid`, which was not accurate).
2. Wrapping all the code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener. JS that depends on elements on a page needs to wait for the page to build first, that's what `DOMContentLoaded` is.

Comment: 2. is not required if the script is below the main HTML.

Comment: @ChrisG, still a best practice.

Comment: That's subjective, but disregarding that, it's not "missing from [OPs] JS".

Comment: @ChrisG, we don't actually know that. OP's snippet does not indicate when the JS loads.

Comment: If we don't know whether it's missing, it's not "missing". Maybe OP *does* have a wrapper but only posted relevant code, as they're supposed to?

Comment: @ChrisG, putting scripts in the head and using `defer` and `async` attributes ensures that the scripts do not block page load, but can be downloaded simultaneously while the rest of the page is parsed. It is a vital part of improving the user experience and perceived page load times. If you are aware of a competing best practice to this methodology, please share it.

Comment: There's no need to explain to me how a browser works; I'm only questioning your decision to include an assertion about optional "missing" wrappers in a question that is completely unrelated. This question is about selecting an element that's a bunch of nodes down the tree, not about events or execution order.

Comment: @Paster, were you aware of the `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` wrapper for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution. Hope this helps.

```js
var d = document.querySelector("#testid a");
var dataLayer = []

d.onclick = function () {
  dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'})
  console.log(dataLayer.length)
}
```

```html
<div id="testid"><div><div><a href="#">Button 1</a><div><div><div>
```